# How to chain Sprockets 3+ processors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I'm trying to make a small gem that renders some javascript and the passes it on to the Sprocket's JST processor. So the file would look like `foo.jst.bar` and then you can call it via `JST[foo]()`

I can't figure out how processor chaining happens. I thought it would be handled automatically via registered mime-types? Since JST processor is registered to deal with `application/javastcript+function` (see: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets.rb#L169) all I need to do is to register my processor like so:

```
env.register_mime_type 'text/x-bar-template', extensions: ['.bar', '.jst.bar']
env.register_transformer 'text/x-bar-template', 'application/javascript+function', Bar::Processor
```

This is not doing anything. If I forget about chaining and define my own `JST` namespace thing, it works just fine. I feel I'm missing something super obvious that doesn't chain to JSTProcessor.